# Best Latex Template for Informal Paper Revision

Tags: templates

I need a LaTeX template for my paper-in-preparation.

To make it easier to revise (note taking, correction etc.) I find the traditional templates such as LNCS not so useful because i) the font size and ii) the line spacing and width.

Could you please suggest a template that makes it way more easier for one to revise papers, technical reports etc? Maybe smaller margins and more line spacing?

Which templates do you find useful?

Comment: why a "template" at all, I'd just keep everything to a minimum and just use `article` (and perhaps `geometry` if you want to adjust the margins) keeping the requirements basic means it is easy to switch a final version to whatever publisher class you need.

Comment: *Template* in the LaTeX world is an often misused word. Stick to `article` and save yourself a lot of time and trouble. There is really nothing more to say here. -- Gunnar, hunter and destroyer of *templates*.

Comment: @Johannes_B: You should definitely rename yourself ;-)

Comment: Are there any news here?

Comment: @Johannes_B after a long time, I decided that you are absolutely right. Using geometry package has done the trick. Also, it is much more flexible.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ^^^^^^ Wanna write up an answer?

Comment: @david i agree :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't really need  a "template" at all, I'd just keep everything to a minimum and just use `article` (and perhaps `geometry` if you want to adjust the margins).

Keeping the requirements basic means it is easy to switch a final version to whatever publisher class you need.